# How to bypass the openzeppelin-contracts Address.sol check and "tx.origin == _caller"

Tags: security, addresses, openzeppelin

I am trying to create a smart contract for to mint NFT and token for security purpose, but I often got stuck with the contract checking, does anyone know if I can bypass those checking?

Comment: Please follow the instructions on creating a minimum reproducible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I dont know if you are going to update the question but the reason for those check is not for them to be bypassed, is for them to keep the contract secure